# Like button in Django + AJAX (dubl)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to implement a like button in my project. I want to do this without page reloading, so I googled and decided to use JS's AJAX, but there is one problem, I have absolutely zero knowledge in Javascript and I don't know how this s*** works.

So, take a look at my code, I hope someone could help me 
Or there is a dead end for me 
**Thanks in advance** :)

**Here's views.py**

```py
def like_place(request, pk):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        place = Place.objects.get(id=pk)
        user = request.user

        if user in place.place_likes.all():
            place.place_likes.remove(user)
        else:
            place.place_likes.add(user)

        place_likes_count = place.place_likes.count()

        return JsonResponse({'likes_count': place_likes_count})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request.'}, status=400)
```

**Here's my html page**

```html
 <div class="search-and-filters">
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Search by cafe name">
      <select name="country_filter" style="text-align: center;">
        <option value="">Search by country</option>
      </select>
      <select name="city_filter">
        <option value="">Search by city</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit">Find Place</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="feed-container">
    <div class="comments-section">
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment-nickname">Никнейм</div>
          <div class="comment-details">commented at (название заведения)</div>
          <div class="comment-text">Комментарий</div>
          <div class="comment-date">3 дня назад</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="posts-section">
      <div class="post">
      {% for place in places %}
      <div class="post-title"><a href="{% url 'place_page' place.id %}" style="color: black;">{{ place.place_name }}</a></div>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="button button-like like-button" data-place-id="{{ place.id }}" style="border: none; background-color: transparent" name="like-button">
          <i class="{% if user in place.place_likes.all %}fas{% else %}far{% endif %} fa-heart like-icon"></i>
          <span id="like-count-{{ place.id }}">{{ place.number_of_likes }}</span>
        </button>
      </form>
      <div class="post-details">
        <div class="post-info">
          <div class="user-info">
            <span class="posted-by">Posted by <a href="{% url 'profile_page' place.created_by.id %}" style="color: black;"><b>{{ place.created_by.username }}</b></a></span>
            <span class="date">at {{ place.created }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="cafe-info">
            <div>{{ place.place_country }}, {{ place.place_city }}</div>
            <div>{{ place.place_street }}</div>
            <div> Place Rating : {{ place.place_rating }}/10</div>
            <div> Coffee Rating : {{ place.coffee_rating }}/10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-image">
          <a href="{% url 'place_page' place.id %}">
          <img src="{{ place.place_photo.url }}" alt="Cafe Photo"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="friends-section">
      <ul class="friend-list">
        <li class="friend-item"></li>
        <li class="friend-item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}


{% block javascript %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(input[name="like-button"]).bind('click', function() {
            console.log('hello111')
            print('hello')
            event.preventDefault();
            const placeId = $(this).data("place-id");
            const url = `{% url 'like_place' 0 %}`.replace('0', placeId);

            $.post(url, function(data) {
                if ('likes_count' in data) {
                    const placeLikesCount = data.likes_count;
                    $(`#like-count-${placeId}`).text(placeLikesCount);
                } else {
                    console.error('Ошибка в ответе AJAX:', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

So, if you need, this is my place db model

```py
class Place(models.Model):     
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place_country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    place_city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #### LINK CITY TO THE COUNTRY RELS
    place_street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place_photo = models.ImageField(null=False)
    place_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='place_like')
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    place_rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    coffee_rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    wifi_good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Where's the problem?

When i Click on the like button, in the terminal i see

```
[31/Jul/2023 19:48:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 16660
```

and my app redirect me to the blank page with JSON dictionary

I want to implement a like button in my project. I want to do this without page reloading, so I googled and decided to use JS's AJAX, but there is one problem, I have absolutely zero knowledge in Javascript and I don't know how this s*** works.

So, take a look at my code, I hope someone could help me 
Or there is a dead end for me 
**Thanks in advance** :)

**Here's views.py**

```py
def like_place(request, pk):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        place = Place.objects.get(id=pk)
        user = request.user

        if user in place.place_likes.all():
            place.place_likes.remove(user)
        else:
            place.place_likes.add(user)

        place_likes_count = place.place_likes.count()

        return JsonResponse({'likes_count': place_likes_count})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request.'}, status=400)
```

**Here's my html page**

```html
 <div class="search-and-filters">
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="Search by cafe name">
      <select name="country_filter" style="text-align: center;">
        <option value="">Search by country</option>
      </select>
      <select name="city_filter">
        <option value="">Search by city</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit">Find Place</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="feed-container">
    <div class="comments-section">
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment-nickname">Никнейм</div>
          <div class="comment-details">commented at (название заведения)</div>
          <div class="comment-text">Комментарий</div>
          <div class="comment-date">3 дня назад</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="posts-section">
      <div class="post">
      {% for place in places %}
      <div class="post-title"><a href="{% url 'place_page' place.id %}" style="color: black;">{{ place.place_name }}</a></div>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button class="button button-like like-button" data-place-id="{{ place.id }}" style="border: none; background-color: transparent" name="like-button">
          <i class="{% if user in place.place_likes.all %}fas{% else %}far{% endif %} fa-heart like-icon"></i>
          <span id="like-count-{{ place.id }}">{{ place.number_of_likes }}</span>
        </button>
      </form>
      <div class="post-details">
        <div class="post-info">
          <div class="user-info">
            <span class="posted-by">Posted by <a href="{% url 'profile_page' place.created_by.id %}" style="color: black;"><b>{{ place.created_by.username }}</b></a></span>
            <span class="date">at {{ place.created }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="cafe-info">
            <div>{{ place.place_country }}, {{ place.place_city }}</div>
            <div>{{ place.place_street }}</div>
            <div> Place Rating : {{ place.place_rating }}/10</div>
            <div> Coffee Rating : {{ place.coffee_rating }}/10</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-image">
          <a href="{% url 'place_page' place.id %}">
          <img src="{{ place.place_photo.url }}" alt="Cafe Photo"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="friends-section">
      <ul class="friend-list">
        <li class="friend-item"></li>
        <li class="friend-item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}


{% block javascript %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(input[name="like-button"]).bind('click', function() {
            console.log('hello111')
            print('hello')
            event.preventDefault();
            const placeId = $(this).data("place-id");
            const url = `{% url 'like_place' 0 %}`.replace('0', placeId);

            $.post(url, function(data) {
                if ('likes_count' in data) {
                    const placeLikesCount = data.likes_count;
                    $(`#like-count-${placeId}`).text(placeLikesCount);
                } else {
                    console.error('Ошибка в ответе AJAX:', data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

So, if you need, this is my place db model

```py
class Place(models.Model):     
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place_country = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.Country', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) 
    place_city = models.ForeignKey('cities_light.City', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True) #### LINK CITY TO THE COUNTRY RELS
    place_street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    place_photo = models.ImageField(null=False)
    place_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='place_like')
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    place_rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    coffee_rating = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(10.0)])
    wifi_good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Where's the problem?

When i Click on the like button, in the terminal i see

```
[31/Jul/2023 19:48:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 16660
```

and my app redirect me to the blank page with JSON dictionary
like this

```
{"likes_count": 1}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not correctly preventing the native form submission. jQuery's `bind` method is deprecated, you should be using `on` instead. And your callback function should _take_ the event object as first parameter, `function(event) { event.preventDefault(); ... }`

Comment: can you provide correct code? I'm kinda misunderstood

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ And how to properly handle preventing the event's default action, I already mentioned.

Comment: (And next time, please do not post a duplicate of your own question, especially not when it is only half a day old. If you have information to add, you can edit the existing question.)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the form is submitting even though you're trying to handle like button click with Ajax to fix this you need to prevent the form submission when the like button is clicked.
change your input to button:

```
$('button[name="like-button"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // add this line to prevent form submission
   
});
```

so the javascript part should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[name="like-button"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const placeId = $(this).data("place-id");
        const url = `{% url 'like_place' 0 %}`.replace('0', placeId);

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            if ('likes_count' in data) {
                const placeLikesCount = data.likes_count;
                $(`#like-count-${placeId}`).text(placeLikesCount);
            } else {
                console.error('Ошибка в ответе AJAX:', data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I hope this helps you.